# Need Regular Expression Help To Match Google Images Pattern

Tags: php, regex

i needed PHP regular expression function to match Goolge Images Urls. Actually i want to fetch all images Urls from my Database, who hosted on Google Servers.

Google Images Urls look like this.

> https://lh3.ggpht.com/I5NYwBKCBphMQvQLC7DWgTbMabYxqrwR83wEe2o4IryOJBfcndjz4ZN4cc2rMNPlCA=w124

Please, someone help my to prepare PHP function, it fetch all urls at this pattern....

thanks

Comment: Is https://lh3.ggpht.com/ is constant for allurls?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "like this"? I cannot extract a pattern from a single url only.

Comment: If you're fetching the URLs from your database, then shouldn't you use your database's flavor of regex, rather than PHP's?

Comment: All urls using pattern look like "https://ab1.domain.com/AbCdeFgH123=w123"

Comment: if you search google play apps store, all images using pattern same like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So from what you provided I guess

```
/https:\/\/\w\w\d\.\w+\.com\/[\w-]+=w\d{3}/
```

should suffice (in short: HTTPS protocol, third-level-`.com`-domain, long alphanumeric path, followed by an equals sign, the letter `w` and the number of pixels).

Comment: First, thanks for help, if you check google using subdomain look like, "lh3" its means, two words and 1 digit, and long string show, google using "word", "digit", underscore, hyphen in it. in last, string, 1 word and 3 digit.

Comment: I have adapted the answer, though I'm not sure whether the width parameter really always is only three digits.

Comment: i tested this pattern in "preg_match" and "preg_match_all" PHP function, but it does not match.. following string

Comment: Oops, missed a significant repetetion :-/

Comment: great, yeah pattern matching...! Please let me know, [\w-] represent mixed string or what?

Comment: It's a [character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) consisting of the shorthand for `[A-Za-z0-9_]` and the hyphen.

Comment: in some images, google using 2 digit, so d{3} not working there, How i can match 2 or 3 digit? please let me know, condion